# Azure B2C Reply Url does not accept any value other than https://myapp.onmicrosoft.com

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I created an application in Azure B2C and a few months ago I was able to provide any kind of reply url, as long it was secure (https://) and in the same domain as other reply urls.

Now I can't create any reply URL's other than https://myapp.onmicrosoft.com.

It says: "Cannot update Application: One of the reply URLs provided for application 'xxxxxxx' contains a word that is not allowed. Please change the reply URL and try again."

Even something like https://localhost:12345 does not work, which worked before.

It looks like a bug in Azure B2C, is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is a bug. Hope MS fix soon

Comment: There appears to be an outage in the app registration experience at the moment. Checkout [this github issue that the team is updating](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/95#issuecomment-314932102)

Comment: You shouldn't see the bug anymore

Comment: Yes, it works again. Thanks all!!

Comment: @TeunisWestbroek, I'd recommend deleting this question since this isn't applicable anymore and it isn't a coding question but more a service outage.